# How to make a discord.py converter pass thorugh a argument and time return a value

Tags: discord.py, converters

what i want to do is something like this:
have a command *modifyImage*

```py
@commands.command()
async def modifyImage(ctx: Context, imgName: DefaultImageConverter, size: int):
    img = imageList[imgName]
    img.scale(size)
```

a command *setDefaltImage*

```py
@commands.command()
async def setdefaultImage(ctx: Context, imgName: str):
    global defaultImg
    defaultImg = imgName
```

and a converter *DefaultImageConverter*

```py
class DefaultImageConverter(commands.Converter):
async def convert(self, ctx, imgName):
    if imgName not in imageList:
        if defaultImg != '':
            return defaultImg
        if defaultImg == '':
            ctx.reply("you didn't pass a image and doesn't have a defalt image")
            raise BadArgument
    elif imgName in imageList:
        return imgName
```

the `DefaultImageConverter` would be a converter that checks the a image exist and return them, if not, return the *default image* if exist, if even that doesn't existe, he will raise a error

**but** the program doesn't work this way, because if i use the command `!modifyImage 100` the number '100' won't be passed to the parameter `size`, because technically the conversion worked

so i need to do

```py
@commands.command()
async def modifyImage(ctx: Context, imgName: typing.Optional[DefaultImageConverter], size: int):
    if imgName == None:
        if defaultImg != '':
            imgName =  defaultImg
        else:
            ctx.send("you didn't pass a image and doesn't have a defalt image")
            return
            
    img = imageList[imgName]
    img.scale(size)
```

and the converter be

```py
class DefaultImageConverter(commands.Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, imgName):
        if imgName not in imageList:
            return BadArgument
        else:
            return imgName
```

what i need to do for use something like the first option, because the `if imgName == None:` part become very repetetive, and every function that modify a image has this

---

tl;dr

i want a way to do a discord.py converter, at the same time, return a value, and pass the current argument value to the next parameter

the only way that i know to the converter 'pass the argument' is using a typing.Optional and raising a error in the converter, but doing this the argument become `None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the program doesn't work this way, because if i use the command `!modifyImage 100` the number '100' won't be passed to the parameter size, because technically the conversion worked

Just like regular functions, you can't put optional arguments before mandatory ones. You need to reorder your arguments so that your `size` is expected first, *then* your `imgName`.

> what i need to do for use something like the first option, because the `if imgName == None:` part become very repetetive, and every function that modify a image has this

Your first option was mostly fine, you just need to swap the arguments as mentioned, and include the `None` check in your converter. Try this:

```py
class DefaultImageConverter(commands.Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, imgName):
        if imgName is None or imgName not in imageList:
            if defaultImg:
                return defaultImg
            else:
                ctx.reply("you didn't pass a image and doesn't have a defalt image")
                raise BadArgument
        else:
            return imgName

@commands.command()
async def modifyImage(ctx: Context, size: int,
                      imgName: typing.Optional[DefaultImageConverter]):
    img = imageList[imgName]
    img.scale(size)
```

Then your `!modifyImage 100` example should work, as well as `!modifyImage 100 someImage`.